# Specific order for patch

Tags: magento2, setup

I'm new in Magento 2.

I create several Patchs in Project/Module/Setup/Patch :

- Patch 1
- Patch 2
- Patch 3

I set all my patchs, one by one, with :

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

In DB, all it's OK : a new line is created in 'patch_list'.

But how can I specified the order, for example, if I want Patch 2 in first, then Patch 3, then Patch 1 ?
Where I need to add this specification ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To define a dependency in a patch, add the method `public static function getDependencies()` to the patch class and return the class names of the patches this patch depends on. The dependency can be in any module.

```
public static function getDependencies()
{
    return [
        \SomeVendor\SomeModule\Setup\Patch\Data\SomePatch::class
    ];
}
```

The following code sample defines a data patch class that has a dependency.

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    namespace Magento\DummyModule\Setup\Patch\Data;

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

    /**
     */
    class DummyPatch
        implements DataPatchInterface,
        PatchRevertableInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface
         */
        private $moduleDataSetup;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
        ) {
            /**
             * If before, we pass $setup as argument in install/upgrade function, from now we start
             * inject it with DI. If you want to use setup, you can inject it, with the same way as here
             */
            $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function apply()
        {
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
            //The code that you want apply in the patch
            //Please note, that one patch is responsible only for one setup version
            //So one UpgradeData can consist of few data patches
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public static function getDependencies()
        {
            /**
             * This is a dependency to another patch. Dependency should be applied first
             * One patch can have few dependencies
             * Patches do not have versions, so if in old approach with Install/Upgrade data scripts you used
             * versions, right now you need to point from the patch with a higher version to patch with lower version
             * But please, note, that some of your patches can be independent and can be installed in any sequence
             * So use dependencies only if this important for you
             */
            return [
                SomeDependency::class
            ];
        }

        public function revert()
        {
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
            //Here should go code that will revert all operations from `apply` method
            //Please note, that some operations, like removing data from column, that is in role of foreign key reference
            //is dangerous, because it can trigger ON DELETE statement
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getAliases()
        {
            /**
             * This internal Magento method, that means that some patches with time can change their names,
             * but changing name should not affect installation process, that's why if we will change the name of the patch
             * we will add alias here
             */
            return [];
        }
    }
```